# How to stop the slider by mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I am using this code 
http://jsfiddle.net/sagive/cAsB3/

my question is how to pause the slider when mouse is on the pictures(hover).

```
    $.getJSON('assets/json/slides.json', function(data) {
    $("h2").html(data[0].title);
        $.each(data, function (i, f) {
            if(i>0){
                $("#exampleSlider").append("<li><img src=" + f.content + "/></li>");
            }
        });
   });


$(function () {

/* SET PARAMETERS */
var change_img_time     = 3000; 
var transition_speed    =200;

var simple_slideshow    = $("#exampleSlider"),
    listItems           = simple_slideshow.children('li'),
    listLen             = listItems.length,
    i                   = 0,


    changeList = function () {

        listItems.eq(i).fadeOut(transition_speed, function () {
            i += 1;
            if (i === listLen) {
                i = 0;
            }
            listItems.eq(i).fadeIn(transition_speed);
        });
    };
listItems.not(':first').hide();
setInterval(changeList, change_img_time);
});
```

and I have another question also: when I import pic with get JSON. the directory in browser is like this:

```
assets/img/pic1.jpg/
```

how can I remove the `/` at the end of directory. because with `/` in is not shows the pic in browsers
 thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if($('#exampleSlider').is(":hover") == true){
    return false;
}
```